# VBA compare two lists and remove row with duplicate value in different column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have two lists with several columns. Some columns are different, but many are the same and are in different order.

How can I compare List1 to List2, and (for example) delete row 34 of List1 because cell E34 of List1 = H10 of List2

Because of predetermined formats: List1 begins on row 12 (headers in row 11), and List2 begins on row 7 (headers in row6)

```
Sub ClearDuplicate()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim C1row As Long
Dim C2row As Long
Dim C2TotalRows As Long
Dim SerialNumber As String
Dim NoDups As Long

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Open Report")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("FNDWRR")
sht2.Activate
C2TotalRows = Application.CountA(Range("H:H"))
C1row = 12

Do While sht1.Cells(C1row, 5).Value <> ""

SerialNumber = sht1.Cells(C1row, 5).Value

    For C2row = 7 To C2TotalRows

        If SerialNumber = Cells(C2row, 8).Value Then
            
            sht1.Activate
            Rows(C1row).Delete
            NoDups = NoDups + 1
            C1row = C1row - 1
            sht2.Activate
            Exit For
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
    C1row = C1row + 1

Loop
    
MsgBox NoDups & " Duplicates were removed"

End Sub
```

Comment: I would probably build a `Dictionary` for each column, and add the `.Value` from each cell as the "key" and the row number as the "value." Then make your comparison using the `.Keys` from each of the dictionaries and, based on what you find, you can use the stored row numbers to delete/edit/modify the worksheet. See [this site](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/excel-vba-dictionary-keys-and-items/) for some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Duplicate Rows (`Application.Match`)

- The following will delete all rows in the Destination Worksheet in which a value in a given column is also found in a given column of the Source Worksheet.
- The code (`deleteDupeRows`) is 'simplified' by using two functions: `refNonEmptyColumn` and `getCombinedRange`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteDupeRows()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "FNDWRR"
    Const sFirst As String = "H7"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Open Report"
    Const dFirst As String = "E12"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Debug.Print wb.Name
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = refNonEmptyColumn(sws.Range(sFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print sws.Name, srg.Address
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refNonEmptyColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print dws.Name, drg.Address
    
    ' Combine matching destination cells into a range.
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dCount As Long
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)) Then
            Set crg = getCombinedRange(crg, dCell)
            dCount = dCount + 1
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    ' Delete entire rows of matching destination cells in one go.
    If crg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found.", vbExclamation, "Dupes"
    Else
        'crg.Worksheet.Activate
        'crg.EntireRow.Select
        'Debug.Print crg.Worksheet.Name, crg.Address
        'Debug.Print crg.Worksheet.Name, crg.EntireRow.Address
        crg.EntireRow.Delete
        If dCount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "1 duplicate removed.", vbInformation, "Dupes"
        Else
            MsgBox dCount & " duplicates removed.", vbInformation, "Dupes"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function refNonEmptyColumn( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "refNonEmptyColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCell.Cells(1)
            Dim lCell As Range
            Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                Set refNonEmptyColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getCombinedRange( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "getCombinedRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If AddRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getCombinedRange = BuiltRange
        End If
    Else
        If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
        Else
            If AddRange.Worksheet Is BuiltRange.Worksheet Then
                Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
            End If
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: I tried running your code and I got an "Subscript out of range (Error 9)" error  for                ```                                                                                                                                                 ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName) <---
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = refNonEmptyColumn(sws.Range(sFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print sws.Name, srg.Address                                                                                          ```